# null pointer exception occuring in java servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, nullpointerexception

I am developing a comment forum that is people will comment and can see their comments after posting but i am getting `null pointer exception in servlet`.

index.jsp

```
<form action="Comment" method="post">

  <textarea style="resize: none;" cols="30" rows="3" id="myTextarea" name="myTextarea"></textarea>

</form>
```

Comment servlet

```
  try{
    String comment=request.getParameter("myTextarea");

       ArrayList al1=null;
        ArrayList emp_list =new ArrayList();
         al1.add(comment);       
         emp_list.add(al1);                 
         request.setAttribute("empList",emp_list);        
        String nextJSP = "/result.jsp";
       RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
      dispatcher.forward(request,response);
    }       
    catch(Exception e){       
    out.println("exception"+e);//exception coming 

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `al1` will be null when you try to add to it:

```
ArrayList al1=null;
ArrayList emp_list =new ArrayList();
al1.add(comment);
```

Try changing the first line to:

```
ArrayList al1 = new ArrayList();
```

This will result in forwarding an array list inside an array list to your next jsp page. It might be simpler to just do:

```
ArrayList emp_list =new ArrayList();
emp_list.add(comment);
```

...and remove the varialble `al1` altogether.

Comment: yes this solved the problem, i just need few help , how can i get this `emp_list.add(comment)` in `result.jsp` ? will i get multiple comments?

Comment: Your call to `setAttribute` should make it a request parameter you can access in `result.jsp`. No, as it is you will get one comment inside an array in the parameter `empList`.

Comment: ya i am getting only one comment and it is getting replaced if i am entering a different comment, how can i get multiple comments? please help me little bit

Comment: @sujit - A lot depends on the other parts of your code. Often, you would just write the comment to a database in this handler, and read a list from there for display inside your results page. Can you create another question with more explanation of the path the data takes?

Answer (score 1):

Your al1 arraylist is instantiated to null!
try

```
ArrayList<String> al1 = new ArrayList<String>();
al1.add(comment);
```

Comment: i have added `string comment to al1 by al1.add(comment)`

Comment: when you call al1.add(comment), you're not adding the string to the an arraylist object, you're adding your "comment" to "null" because you instantiated al1 = null;

Answer (score 0):

Dude you are assigning the reference to a null. that is al1.add(), just assign it with the memory using new, it will solve your problem....... Enjoy........